# How do I pass a string from Javascript to the src part of an image tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, image, tags

I've written an extremely simple Javascript function.  All it does is randomly selects an image filename (file.png, for example) and and passes it over with getElementById.

```
var nameA=fileNames[randnumA];
document.getElementByID("image1").firstChild.nodeValue= nameA;
```

Of course, there's other stuff to go along with that, but I didn't feel it necessary to be included.  All I'm doing is passing a string over from Javascript.  Simple enough.

The problem is that I want to use that string as the source for an HTML  tag.  I'm a noob, and haven't done this before, so a simple explanation would be awesome.  My current code in HTML is this:

```
<img src=<span id="image1">&nbsp;</span>>
```

I didn't expect it to work, as placing tags within other tags doesn't feel right.

Any ideas as to how I'm supposed to do this?  Thanks everybody, I appreciate the help.

Also, the function is definitely being called.  I have it as an onLoad in the `<body>` tag.

Comment: I almost want to +1 this question for the quote: "placing tags within other tags doesn't feel right".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*blank stare*

```
<img id="image1" />
```

JS:

```
var nameA = fileNames[randnumA];
document.getElementById('image1').src = nameA;
```

Comment: I said I was a noob!  Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
var nameA=fileNames[randnumA];
document.getElementByID("image1").src = nameA;
```

HTML:

```
<img id="image1" />
```

Comment: Aha, beat you by one second XD